# What if value for select option is not specified in html select tag

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Recently, I mistakenly didn't specified the value for a select tag in a form of my project. But It was working properly and getting the correct values. Does that mean If I don't specify the value of a option then it assumes the Placeholder/What I am showing for that option as the value.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="category">
        <option>Action</option>
        <option>Horror</option>
        <option>Adventure</option>
        <option>Comedy</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add some code, so that we can replicate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically you're right, seeing MDN docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

> Each  element should have a value attribute containing the
>   data value to submit to the server when that option is selected; if no
>   value attribute is included, the value defaults to the text contained
>   inside the element. You can include a selected attribute on an
>    element to make it selected by default when the page first
>   loads.

so yeah you're right, it assumes what you're showing in the html tag as the value

Comment: Thanks...I understand it now

Answer (score 3):

the answer from w3schools

Note: If the value attribute is not specified, the content will be passed as a value instead.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you assign no value to each options, the text will be sent to the form action. The reason why we specify values is because it's easier to work with. You could say the text inbetween the option tags is meant to be shown to the users and the value attribute is meant for the application behind when submitting the form.

**Example:**

```html
<select>
<option value="Pixel">   Google Pixel 4XL</option>
<option value="G8X">     LG G8X ThinQ Dual Screen</option>
<option value="Iphone">  Iphone 11 Pro Max</option>
</select>
```

Let's say I wanted to check if the selected option was `G8X`, then I wouldn't have to write something like this:

```cs
if (option == "LG G8X ThinQ Dual Screen")
{
   // do something
}
```